# Add div element if class is present

Tags: html, invision-power-board

Wanting to add a div element if a class is present on the page.

This is for IPS forum software. Reached out to them about this and their response was that they would charge for a custom theme design. Would rather do this myself if possible (bit too expensive otherwise).

I want to display a specific div for the "compose new private message" modal popup without displaying it on all other modal popups. Can't use body page controllers so I'm guessing my only option, other than having the PM modal inherit from a new template, would be to try and display a div if a certain class exists.

Comment: Is the div you want to display a child element of the parent element which has the class?

Comment: No, it's just a styled div that will display a message. For IPS, it's just a warning message so that I can remind my members that posting rules apply to PMs as well. Want it to display just above the "To" field but at the moment, affixing that div to the current template causes it to appear on all popop modals.

Answer (score 0):

Templates are stored in the database for IPB.  You can utilize the Admin system to go in and edit the templates.  There is an extensive series of menus that give you access to individual template code, for example, under Messenger, there is sendNewPersonalTopicForm, PMQuickForm, and sendReplyForm.

It should be relatively easy to go into those templates, find the markup you want and add a container div where appropriate.

For example, for a 3.x board, you find something like this:

```
<div id='message_compose' class='post_form'>
    <form id='msgForm' style='display:block' 
    action="{parse url="module=messaging&amp;section=send&amp;do=send" base="publicWithApp"}" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

This seems fairly simple code to alter.

Comment: Unfortunately, IPS 4.2 is quite a bit different. This is the popupTemplate that all popup modals inherit from.

https://pastebin.com/6Gw4QzGJ

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a Plugin with a theme hook. You can put your logic in the php file and assign your hook to show up exactly where you want it.